# Where can I find out how or where to renew SSL certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a webapp that was handed to me when I started working at my current job. Today the SSL certificate has expired and I was wondering where or how can I figure out the origin of my certificate is to renew it?

I was able to find the .crt and .key files, if that makes any difference.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while Information Security covers security questions and ServerFault covers admin questions.

Comment: You can look at https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcertificates%5D+renew and https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/certificate+renew

Comment: You can "renew" it anywhere. No need to absolutely use the same CA. Except in some very specific cases (if you have DNS CAA records, if you use DANE, etc.)